# Excel: Count specific words in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to count specific words in cell and display the total. I have searched and tried solutions of several similar questions but couldn't. Here in the example below Column A has the text, Column B has unique words (criteria for search) that need to be counted and Column C is the count. Please help

Example:

```
|     Column A          |     Column B      |   Column C    |
|  AA; BB; CC; AE; DE   |    AA; DE; CC     |      3        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function StringCounter(sBig As String, sKeys As String) As Long

ary = Split(sBig, ";")
bry = Split(sKeys, ";")
StringCounter = 0

For Each b In bry
    If InStr(1, ";" & sBig & ";", ";" & b & ";") <> 0 Then
        StringCounter = StringCounter + UBound(Filter(ary, b)) + 1
    End If
Next b
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

If a word like `AA` appeared more than once in cell **A1**, the function would count each occurrence .

**EDIT#1:**

This version will work with or without spaces:

```
Public Function StringCounter(sBig As String, sKeys As String) As Long

    sBig = Replace(sBig, " ", "")
    sKeys = Replace(sKeys, " ", "")

    ary = Split(sBig, ";")
    bry = Split(sKeys, ";")
    StringCounter = 0

    For Each b In bry
        If InStr(1, ";" & sBig & ";", ";" & b & ";") <> 0 Then
            StringCounter = StringCounter + UBound(Filter(ary, b)) + 1
        End If
    Next b
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this works very well. However, there is one issue - If a cell has one value AE in Column A and Column B has AA; AE; CC the count in Column C is shown is 0. Could it be because of semicolon or spaces?

Comment: @user7357285  I made a small update to the code...please re-copy it.

Comment: @user7357285  I need to make additional changes to accommodate the spaces.

Comment: I added the spaces to your code and it works perfectly. I will mark the question as answered. 5 stars to you - thanks a lot

Comment: @user7357285  See my **EDIT#1**